# binary bomb phase 2 retrieve value in 0xc(%ebx)

Tags: assembly, gdb, compare, offset

I'm working on the binary bomb, and was trying to figure out how to get the  values being compared inside the cmp statement, my understanding is that eax is what i entered in, and 0xc(%ebx) is what the answer should be for that 1st/2nd/etc. Of the 6 numbers. The code i'm looking through is

```
0x08048e22 <+0>:     push   %ebp
0x08048e23 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048e25 <+3>:     sub    $0x48,%esp
0x08048e28 <+6>:     mov    %ebx,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048e2b <+9>:     mov    %esi,-0x8(%ebp)
0x08048e2e <+12>:    mov    %edi,-0x4(%ebp)
0x08048e31 <+15>:    lea    -0x30(%ebp),%ebx
0x08048e34 <+18>:    mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
0x08048e38 <+22>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048e3b <+25>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048e3e <+28>:    call   0x8049248 <read_six_numbers>
0x08048e43 <+33>:    lea    -0x24(%ebp),%edi
0x08048e46 <+36>:    mov    $0x0,%esi
0x08048e4b <+41>:    mov    (%ebx),%eax
=>0x08048e4d <+43>:    cmp    0xc(%ebx),%eax
0x08048e50 <+46>:    je     0x8048e57 <phase_2+53>
0x08048e52 <+48>:    call   0x8049206 <explode_bomb>
0x08048e57 <+53>:    add    (%ebx),%esi
0x08048e59 <+55>:    add    $0x4,%ebx
0x08048e5c <+58>:    cmp    %edi,%ebx
0x08048e5e <+60>:    jne    0x8048e4b <phase_2+41>
0x08048e60 <+62>:    test   %esi,%esi
0x08048e62 <+64>:    jne    0x8048e69 <phase_2+71>
0x08048e64 <+66>:    call   0x8049206 <explode_bomb>
0x08048e69 <+71>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%ebx
0x08048e6c <+74>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%esi
0x08048e6f <+77>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edi
0x08048e72 <+80>:    mov    %ebp,%esp
0x08048e74 <+82>:    pop    %ebp
0x08048e75 <+83>:    ret
```

Is what i believe i need to do correct? If not, a hint in the right direction would be appreciated, as well as a way to check what exactly is being compared in that cmp statement.

Thanks!

Comment: `ebx` initially points to the first number entered, followed by the rest of them.

Comment: so would eax be the number necessary? because when checking the registers for info eax tends to match up with what i entered, so wouldn't the value in ebx be what i need to find out?

Comment: Since line `+41` loads into `eax`, it will contain (some of) the numbers you entered. The code is checking some things about the numbers entered.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out =) after a day or so of staring at it i realized all the compare statement was doing is making sure that the 1st and 4th, 2nd and 5th, 3rd and 6th numbers entered were all equivelant. Thanks to jester for the information of ebx pointing to the first local var.